# NodeJS env-var package behaves weirdly

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables

getting this error when trying to get environment variable using `env-var` package ([Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-var))

**Error**

```
file:///x/index.js:3
const PORT = env.get('PORT').default('5432').asString();
                 ^

TypeError: env.get is not a function
    at file:///private/tmp/test/index.js:3:18
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

node version `v16.15.1` npm version `8.11.0`

`index.js`

```
import * as env from "env-var"

const PORT = env.get('PORT').default('5432').asString();
console.log(PORT)
```

`package.json`

```
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
```

`npm ls`

```
test@1.0.0 /x
└── env-var@7.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like it was a `README.md` doc issue

`TL;DR` - use `import env from 'env-var'`

package owner answer on opened GH issue :

```
Can you try import env from 'env-var' instead? That seems to work for me.
but seems like a quick update to the README would be helpful?
```

[GH issue](https://github.com/evanshortiss/env-var/issues/154#issuecomment-1172606531)